# How to write to a file different parameters from different CallBacks with same timestamp?

Tags: ros, timestamp, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I would like to write to a text file different parameters obtained from different topics (scan, raw_imu, odom). I obtained some parameters in different CallBacks like scanCallback poseCallback, imuCallback. I would like to have those output parameters in on file but synchronized (with same frequency, like for example every 1 second.)

I know that can use the commands

```
myfile.open("/home/user/file.ttx");
myfile << "timestamp" << "....  "\n";
```

But I cant make it that all output parameters are written in same time stamp. Like for example

```
time in sec    parameter1   parameter2   parameter3
1                 value      value        value
2                 value      value        value
3                 value      value        value
```

I know that laser scaner and Imu publish with different frequencies.

Any help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/111806/how-to--write-to-a-file-different-parameters-from-different-callbacks-with-same-timestamp?/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-12-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try implementing one callback for all three messages using `message_filters`. You can either use an exact time policy if all topics are exactly in sync or an approximate time policy to allow small differences between their timestamps.
An example and a more detailed description is given here:

http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Policy-Based_Synchronizer_.5BROS_1.1.2B-.5D

In the callback you could finally write the information you need from your three messages into one txt file.

Best

Tim

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2013-12-19**:
I cant implement one Callback as the ros topics are from different sensors( laser scan, Imu and Odom), So I need three Callbacks.Whats the option if I do not implement one Callback???

**Comment by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) on 2014-01-01**:
message_filters allow you to use one callback for multiple messages of any type, so it should not matter if the messages come from different sensors... Or did I miss something? Why do you think you have to use three callbacks?